# Extract HEVC bitstream with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, h.265

I would like to extract the raw .265 bitstream from HEVC mkv file.
I use this:

> ffmpeg.exe -i hevc.mkv -an -vcodec copy -f hevc bitstream.265

I got this error:

> Requested output format 'hevc' is not a suitable output format

However, HEVC demuxer is already implemented and I can extract it to uncompressed raw YUV.
ffmpeg -formats:

```
 File formats:
 D. = Demuxing supported
 .E = Muxing supported
D  hevc            raw HEVC video
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: I think you just need a `-f rawvideo`. Since the codec is copied, that should do it.

Comment: Well it does something, but the result is improper stream, i.e. can't be decoded with HM decoder 12.0 (TappDecoder.exe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, the best solution is to use [MKVToolNix](http://labs.divx.com/node/127905).

```
mkvextract.exe tracks hevc.mkv -f 0:bitstream.265
```

Answer (score 14):

The raw bitstream of H.264/H.265 is typically called the Annex B format. You can create those files with the following FFmpeg commands:

**H.265 to Annex B**

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c:v copy -bsf hevc_mp4toannexb out.h265
```

does the trick with ffmpeg and H.265/HEVC.

**H.264 to Annex B**

For H.264 it's slightly different:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c:v copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb out.h264
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried the ffmpeg solution from Sebastian, but it didn't work for me.  Here is what I did to get just the H.265 bitstream.  I did see that some people suggested setting the output file extension to .bin, but I like h264/h265 as it makes it more clear what kind of bitstream the file contains.

**H.265 to Annex B**

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -c:v copy -bsf hevc_mp4toannexb -f hevc test.h265
```

**H.264 to Annex B**

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -c:v copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -f h264 test.h264
```

*NOTE:  This also works for .mov files and probably for other formats as well.*

Comment: So, you answer is identical to [Sebastian Annies’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/678897/150988#1251326) except you added back in the ``-h`` option that was in the question already (even though [dstob](https://superuser.com/q/678897/150988#770509) recommended leaving it out)?  If you’re going to compare your answer to somebody else’s answer, *compare your answer to the other answer* (i.e., describe how it’s different, and why).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I did try without the -h, but ffmpeg kept giving an error.  I found that frustrating so I posted the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a file extension of `.bin` for your output. This is a raw bitstream file so that should be good enough.

You are doing a video copy so I would recommend leaving out the `-f hevc` and letting ffmpeg handle the format selection. If HEVC has been implemented in your version then it should work.

Also consider going with `-c:v copy` over `-vcodec copy` as the latter is deprecated.

I have a lot of experience with the h265 test model encoder and with using ffmpeg but not with the HEVC muxer in ffmpeg so my information may be inaccurate.

Answer (score -3):

You might want check if you have a recent version of ffmpeg.
If you want a video file without audio, try this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i hevc.mkv -codec:v copy videostream.mkv
```

or:

```
ffmpeg -y -i hevc.mkv -codec:v copy videostream.mp4
```

Comment: The OP asked how to extract the raw stream, not how to mux it into another container.